# It sounds as Lethem... But I'm not sure

Tags: listening

In the video http://www.ted.com/talks/john_lloyd_inventories_the_invisible?language=en#t-592626 at 2:36 there is a phrase "I bet he thought he wished he was invisible ...". What is he saying at the end? "Lethem"? I guess it's about Jonathan Lethem who is author of The Fortress of Solitude. Is it possible?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we are not a transcription service.

Comment: **TED.com (Talks)** provides two buttons, on the bottom right hand corner; one labelled *subtitles*, and the other *transcript*. When you click on the button *subtitle* a menu opens allowing you to choose which language you want  the subtitles to be in. The transcript tool reports the entire talk, word for word, perfectly.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the transcription is available on the actual website.

Comment: The transcription may be wrong, I suppose..

Comment: @AlexM No, the transcription's perfectly correct. I listened all the way through because  I quite enjoyed the talk.  Many thanks for sharing the link, it was interesting.

Answer (score 1):

> I bet he thought he wished he was invisible, don't you?

The speaker is asking the audience a rhetorical question after recounting an embarrassing story of the PM Jeffrey Dickens.

Comment: Thank you! Сould you give me the exact transcription of "don't you" as he's pronouncing it?

Comment: @AlexM - I hear it kind of as *"own'choo?"*  Firstly, John Lloyd has a British accent, which could make his words a little harder to understand if you're not used to it, and when speaking informally, people sometimes de-emphasize the **d** almost to the point of being inaudible, and the **'t y** of *don't you* get run together into a *ch* sound.